# RequestAnimationFrame won't stop logging

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

```
let stopId;

const playVideo = () =>{
    if(isPlaying){
        videoRef.current.pause()
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(stopId)
    }else{
        videoRef.current.play();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(calcTime)
    }
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
}

const calcTime = () =>{
    stopId = window.requestAnimationFrame(calcTime)
    console.log('hey')
}
```

This is for the seeker animation for a video player. I was console logging something when I noticed that it wouldn't stop logging despite pausing the video. The seeker animation stopped but the logging is still going.

Another thing I tried is:

```
const calcTime = () =>{           
    stopId = window.requestAnimationFrame(calcTime)
    console.log('hey')
    setTimeout(() => {
        videoRef.current.pause()
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(stopId)
        console.log('pause')
    }, 5000);
}
```

This would log 'hey' 300 times before stopping and then log 'paused' 300 times before stopping too. I'm so confused on what is happening. Does this mean that the request is still happening when the video is paused and is there going to be a performance issue?

Comment: `stopID` is the id of the first request, not of the latest one. You need to keep setting it in your loop too.

Comment: And calling `setTimeout` in `calcTime` starts a new, separate pause timer every frame.

Comment: @Kaiido I just noticed that `stopID` was undefined when passing it to the cancel request.

Answer (score 0):

I see my problem now. Since I'm using React, the `stopId` is getting nuked whenever the state changes. So I attached a useRef to it and set `stopId.current = window.requestAnimationFrame(calcTime)` and now it properly stops